# What is sonarqube logon webapi

Tags: sonarqube-4.5

We are using Sonarqube version 4.5.
Using curl call I am trying to log on to sonar qube server but I am getting "authenication" error. What is a webapi call to logon to SonarQube server?

Answer (score 1):

There is no dedicated 'login API', SonarQube [Web Services use basic HTTP authentication](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+Service+API#WebServiceAPI-Callingasecuredwebservice) (for the Web Services that do require authentication). So you just need to provide your credentials within the HTTP request itself, e.g. with `curl`:

`curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:9000/api/server/system`