# authentication through web service SonarQube

Tags: web-services, sonarqube

I'm working on a web application that highly requires SonarQube (version 5.3) Web Services.
I want to authenticate to the sonarqube instance using my application.
which web service should I use? 
Another question :
While using the issues web service I noticed that the web service returns the issues of the last project analysed by sonar.
Is there a way to have the issues of all the projects or to have the issues of a given project?

Comment: Provide more description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is sonarqube logon webapi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908563/what-is-sonarqube-logon-webapi)

Comment: more description:
In the login interface when I get the login and the password where should I pass them ?

Comment: issues web service :
lets imagine that I have 2 projects that I  analysed with sonar, so I analyse Project A then I analyse Project B .
the problem that I face is that I want to have trace of the issues of the 2 projects . But when I open the web service (localhost:9000/api/issues/search) I find the issues of the project B

Comment: Did you also notice that search results are paginated? And that you can query by component (project)?

Comment: Thanks #G. Ann 
and for authentication please ?